# Organisation membership with Drupal user account

Tags: drupal, civimember

I am running Drupal 7 with Civi, both on the latest version. I would like a user to be able to register to become a member on behalf of an, which creates an account for a user in Drupal core, who can then edit the organisation details.

I've setup the process so far using CiviCRM Profiles and Webforms. Here is my current setup:

- User applies for an account using profiles and Drupal core using logintoboggan to control this part.
- User account is accepted, and an email is set to a webform link

webform: Number of Contacts: 2

1: Organisation

2: Individual (here I have linked the Individuals Current Employer to the Organisation and added them to a group – which is used in a rule to active the user in Drupal’s core, so the user can login after completing registration)

Users are then prompted to pay . This workflow works, mostly anyway.

A couple of questions:

1: Is using the method of adding the Individual to a group which activates the Drupal core user the best method? I feel that this is messy, especially when the organisations membership is due for renewal and if the organisation doesn’t renew how is the individual account deactivated? Is there a better way?

2: How do I allow the user to edit the organisations details?

I have many other thoughts/questions. But this enough… for now :)

Thanks for your help!

SJ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One comment is that it would be more common to have Contact 1 set as the Individual (current user) and Contact 2 as the Organisation.

In terms of if an Org does not renew - if you have the Individual 'inheriting' the membership, and hence getting added to a Drupal Role via MemberSync then when the Org fails to renew then the Individual will lose any Roles other than Sync.

An alternative would be to use Drupal Rules based on Membership Status and hence Block the user if their membership Expires but that seems unnecessary imo if you give the Authenticate role no extra permissions.

The Individual needs to be given 'permission' over the Organisation via the Relationship, this will allow the Individual to edit some details via their CiviCRM Dashboard, though I would suggest you give them a Drupal Views block linked to a Webform and let them edit the Org details that way.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your message, it has helped a lot. One key word was 'inheriting'. After some research I found the option: Relationship Type when creating a new membership type, now the individual has the same status as the org. Great! Thanks again 

Comment: Excellent - can you accept the answer - help keep SE tidy?

Answer (score 0):

Pete's answer pretty much covers the bases - but make sure to check out the [Relationship Permissions as ACLs](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) extension, which should be a big help.

Comment: Pete's answer did cover it. I'll checkout the extension also. Thanks Jon.